# Error Using Emit from thread with flask socketio python3

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

I'm trying to build an anpplication, that serve a page via web with flask, meanwhile in background start a thread that it's asking for status to another machine and update a variable, also i would like to send that status via socketio to update the webpage (if present otherwise just save the information)

unfortunatelly i'm not able to do that, i'm getting some issue on sending or receiving the messages

**here the python code:**

```
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, copy_current_request_context
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlalchemy as db
from flask_htpasswd import HtPasswdAuth
from sqlalchemy import desc
from threading import Thread, Event
import datetime
import os
import logging
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import hashlib

class config():
    hostip = '0.0.0.0'
    portip = 8080

class statoMacchina():
    status = -1
    mode = -1

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socket = SocketIO(app, async_mode='threading')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()

class getStatusThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 30
        super(getStatusThread, self).__init__()

    def getStatus(self):
        try:
            print(" try " )
            emit('status', {'mode': statoMacchina.mode, 'status' : statoMacchina.status})
        except Exception as ex:   
            print(ex.args)

            #sleep(self.delay)
    def run(self):
        self.getStatus()

thread = getStatusThread()
thread.start()

@socket.on('getstatus', namespace='/command')
def cmdgetstatus():
    emit('replyesec', {'Esec': "listaaaaaa"})
    #emit('status', {'mode': statoMacchina.mode, 'status' : statoMacchina.status})
    global thread
    if not thread.is_alive():
        print("Starting Thread")
        thread = getStatusThread()
        thread.start()

@app.route("/",methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template(
        'index.html', **locals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        tim = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(tim)
        socket.run(app, host=config.hostip, port=config.portip)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("fine")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex.args)
```

here the js code to get the socket message:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  socket.on('status', function(msg) {
      console.log("status - " + msg);
    $("#statoopc").html(msg.mode + " - " + msg.status);
  });
}
```

the issue that i get is if in the function *getStatus* i leave it like this i get:

> ('Working outside of request context.\n\nThis typically means that you
>   attempted to use functionality that needed\nan active HTTP request. 
>   Consult the documentation on testing for\ninformation about how to
>   avoid this problem.',)

if i add socket. before the emit, i don't get eny error, but also i don't get the messages

also for me would be ok to trigger an event from the thread to the mainthread to send the messages if the status change for example, but also i don't know how to do it

ps. i've just added a *getstatus* handlear to do some test sending those from a button on the webpage and it works, it's not working only in the thread

maybe the problem is that i'm trying to emit when there are no connected entities ? how to check that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `emit()` function uses some defaults that come from the request context. If you want to use this function in a place where there is no request context then you have to provide more arguments. In particular, you need to add `room` to indicate who is the recipient of the message, and `namespace`.

Comment: oh thank you so much, adding the namespace seems to work.

Comment: unfortunatelly it's working only when i'm using it in localhost, if i access it via another device, i don't get the socket data in js